# Cant connect pfsense openvpn service using tunnelblick as a client

Tags: vpn, openvpn, pfsense, tunnelblick

I currently have a working pfsense community version firewall.
when I am trying to connect a new user to the openvpn service over the pfsense using the tls+authentication method the user is getting the following error

> Unrecognized option or missing or extra parameter(s) in
> /Library/Application Support/Tunnelblick/Users/ella/internal
> VPN.tblk/Contents/Resources/config.ovpn:4: data-ciphers (2.4.11)

this is the user's config file dump (she is using macos OS)

```
#viscosity startonopen false
#viscosity dhcp true
#viscosity dnssupport true
#viscosity name 

dev tun
persist-tun
persist-key
data-ciphers AES-128-GCM:AES-128-CBC
data-ciphers-fallback AES-128-CBC
auth SHA256
tls-client
client
resolv-retry infinite
remote 12.34.56.78 1234 udp4
verify-x509-name "OpenVPN server certificate" name
auth-user-pass
#cryptoapicert "SUBJ:dudi"
remote-cert-tls server
comp-lzo adaptive
explicit-exit-notify

ca ca.crt
tls-auth ta.key 1
cert cert.crt
key key.key
```

what am I missing here?
*openvpn service version over the pfsense is 1.6
*tunnelblick version is the latest
*my "old" user is working on her machine and her account doesn't work on mine

- I have tested her authentication over the pfsense and everything is working.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

> Unrecognized option or missing or extra parameter(s) in /Library/Application Support/Tunnelblick/Users/ella/internal VPN.tblk/Contents/Resources/config.ovpn:4: data-ciphers (2.4.11)

So the problem is in line 4:

```
data-ciphers AES-128-GCM:AES-128-CBC
```

Googling `data-ciphers` gives us [this page](https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/CipherNegotiation). Indeed, `data-ciphers` is a new option in OpenVPN 2.5, and you appear to be using 2.4.11, where this was known as `cipher`. Upgrade OpenVPN on the client to version 2.5 on the client. Tunnelblick is only a front end for OpenVPN.

Comment: thanks for the answer, I have already done it and it did let me insert username and password but then when the connection was trying to establish I received the following errors: [OpenVPN Connection log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u0gFr.png)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with OpenVPN version and you need to upgrade it.

Here is a temporary solution that worked for me(Windows Machin),just comment or delete data-ciphers and data-ciphers-fallback... as bellow

```
dev tun
persist-tun
persist-key
# data-ciphers AES-128-GCM:AES-128-CBC   <---- delete this line
# data-ciphers-fallback AES-128-CBC      <---- delete this line
auth SHA256
tls-client
client
resolv-retry infinite
remote 12.34.56.78 1234 udp4
verify-x509-name "OpenVPN server certificate" name
auth-user-pass
#cryptoapicert "SUBJ:dudi"
remote-cert-tls server
comp-lzo adaptive
explicit-exit-notify

ca ca.crt
tls-auth ta.key 1
cert cert.crt
key key.key
```